# Реконструкция модального окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, всплывающее-окно, lightbox, окно

Друзья! Прошу помощи. Есть модальное окно, которое открывается по ссылке. Какие нужно внести в него исправления, чтобы это окно открывалось автоматически при загрузке страницы, но не сразу, а по истечении например 60-и секунд?

Вот код скрипта:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//Set the lightbox position in the center of screen
jQuery('.lightbox').css({
    position: 'absolute',
});
//Show the lightbox with background if the link is clicked
jQuery('a.authorization-open').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.lightbox').fadeIn(800);
    jQuery('.authorization-overlay').fadeIn(800);
});
//Hide the lightbox and background if the close link or overlay div is clicked
jQuery('a.authorization-close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.lightbox').fadeOut(800);
    jQuery('.authorization-overlay').fadeOut(800);
});
});
```

Заранее очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать через `.delay()`:

```
var delay = 5; // 5 sec.

$('.lightbox').delay(delay * 1000).fadeIn(800);
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/h4h7g4kj/)

Answer (score 1):

Поробуйте так

```
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('a.authorization-open').click();
    // или 
    jQuery('a.authorization-open').trigger('click');
}, 60000);
```